# MediaWiki: How to clear backlinks cache?

Tags: hyperlink, mediawiki

The red/blue status of links with "arrows" produced by my [NamespacePopups](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:NamespacePopups) extension is not updated on [my site](http://withoutvowels.org) after I create a new page to which the arrow link points (and so it should change from red to blue).

Example of my page with arrows: https://withoutvowels.org/wiki/Tanakh:Genesis_1:7

I think this is because of the backlinks cache.

I have 23253 pages in the namespace `Tanakh:`. Cache of links from every of them should be updated. (It seems that currently the cache contains only old regular links not my new "arrow" links.)

Please help me to update all these pages. The thing I really need is to re-process every of these pages with `ParserAfterTidy` hook. (My hook adds the arrow keys to backlinks cache.)

My current workaround is to run `maintenance/update.php` periodically. This updates the red links to blue as appropriate, but this does not help to make blue links after future edits.

Note that I run `maintenance/runJobs.php` every minute. The software works correctly with these pages which I recently edited, but not with constant non-editable pages in `Tanakh:` namespace.

Note that it all works well if I edit the page with my links. But I cannot edit all pages in `Tanakh:` namespace both because they are a multitude and because they are non-editable.